# Passing variable data between activities (Kotlin) - Passing NULL instead of value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I've been trying to pass two variables from my MainActivity.kt to my HomeActivity.kt; isRunning (Boolean) and time_in_milli_seconds (Long), which are both declared in the MainActivity.

I've read countless tutorials and have been stuck on this for days. I know it's only a few lines of code, but none of the dozens of examples I've seen online (via YT or SE) have addressed the particular issue I'm having. My apologies if this is a duplicate post!

Here's my code:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        var isRunning: Boolean = false;
        var time_in_milli_seconds = 1000L

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
...

    //perform a bunch of other stuff where isRunning and time_in_milli_seconds have values that are not null 
...

            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("isRunningHome", isRunning)
            intent.putExtra("lastKnownTimeLong", time_in_milli_seconds)

}}
```

and in the second activity:

```
    class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

            var intent = intent
            var var2 = intent.getBooleanExtra("isRunningHome")                
            var var1 = intent.getLongExtra("lastKnownTimeLong")

   }}
```

But my HomeActivity will not compile, as each lines var1 and var2 give error "no value passed for parameter DefaultValue". Upon some additional testing, Kotlin appears to be transferring Null values for both of variables, but I for the life of me cannot figure out why - this is the million dollar question. Currently, the program will not even compile.

I've tried:

1) setting the values of isRunning and time_in_milli_seconds to the text parameter of textviews and then applying the intent to their respective text parameters - result - showed NULL value after being "passed" to the HomeActivity.

2)Converting the Long and Boolean variables to strings and passing them as strings, then using getStringExtra in HomeActivity- this worked for the Long variable, but not for Boolean. It also feels morally wrong and is a very bad programming technique.

3) Changing where the intents are put and retrieved (inside or outside of OnCreate, inside and outside functions, etc.). This had no change in my outcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is provide a default

```
var var2 = intent.getBooleanExtra("isRunningHome", false)
var var1 = intent.getLongExtra("lastKnownTimeLong", 0L)
```

Comment: Perfect - can't believe I missed that in the docs. Thanks so much!!